# Single Product Image in wp-ecommerce disappears in IE (it appears well in other browsers)

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer

I have a wp-ecommerce powered wordpress site that has been built for a client.

There is a problem with the Internet Explorer browser only. Single product image in single product individual page disappears and the image cannot be displayed, even though there is still obvious img code in the source code.

Here is the code for image placeholder in wpsc-single_product.php file:

```
<div class="image" style="display: table; width:360; margin: auto;height: 430px; position: relative; overflow: hidden; ">

<a href="<?php echo wpsc_the_product_permalink(); ?>">
      <img style="height: auto; max-height:100%; max-width:100%; margin: 0px auto; overflow:hidden;" class="product_image" id="product_image_<?php echo wpsc_the_product_id(); ?>" alt="<?php echo wpsc_the_product_title(); ?>" title="<?php echo wpsc_the_product_title(); ?>" src="<?php echo wpsc_the_product_thumbnail(get_option('product_image_width'),get_option('product_image_height'),'','single'); ?>"/>
</a>

</div>
```

I would appreciate if anyone could please assist us in fixing the issue to show the image exactly in the single product page.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the source from IE after the page renders?

Comment: Alex Straffin, actually that code I posted above is the code for image after the page rendered. It looks like the max-width:100% is probably the culprit, but I am not sure how to fix it properly to make displayed in IE.

Comment: If that code is from the browser after the page has been processed then your PHP is not being properly handled. PHP should never show to the browser and that is likely your issue if this is post IE rendering.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for that., however I have fixed with max-width set to inherit and display the container to contain table